# Some saved trace ids can not be found in aws xray console

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-xray

I am using the `aws_xray_sdk` library to capture trace IDs, which I then save in a database.

Here's the implementation that works well:

```py
from aws_xray_sdk.core import lambda_launcher,

lambda_context = lambda_launcher.check_in_lambda()
trace_id = lambda_context.get_trace_entity().trace_id if lambda_context else None
```

I have no other functionality related to aws-xray-sdk, besides this implementation.

I'm able to successfully capture trace IDs and store them in the database. However, there's an issue where a few trace IDs saved in the database cannot be found in the AWS X-Ray console.

I expect that the trace IDs I capture using the `aws_xray_sdk` library's `lambda_launcher` method should be visible in the AWS X-Ray console. Although I can successfully capture and save these trace IDs in a database, I've noticed that a few trace IDs stored in the database cannot be located in the X-Ray console. I'm interested in learning if other developers have faced a similar situation and if there's any insight into why this might be happening. Additionally, I'm uncertain whether I need to configure the `xray_recorder` explicitly for proper trace visibility in the AWS X-Ray console, as I'm already able to capture trace IDs and store them in the database with the implementation I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution for this. But, I did however find a way to still find the trace-id by filtering through the logs insights panel in the Cloudwatch console.

---

1. Navigate to the CloudWatch console.
2. Click on "Logs Insights" located on the left side below Logs.
3. Choose the log group.
4. Specify the start and end dates for when the trace ID should have been captured.
5. Enter a query to filter specifically for the trace ID, as demonstrated below:

   ```
   fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log| filter @message like "<trace-id>"| sort @timestamp asc
   ```

   Please note that this query is meant to filter the logs based on the trace ID you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the sampling rules of X-Ray SDK to 100%? Because by default, X-Ray SDK samples the first request of each second and five percent of any additional requests. It is possible that some of the traces you captured are not sampled, meaning they do not get sent to the X-Ray Service.

Read more about sampling rules here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html

Comment: This was a solution I thought about before, but due to possible increase in costs. I skipped this one.